# Type {...} does not satisfy the constraint 'extends Object' error in Typescript

Tags: typescript, resharper, ngrx, typescript-generics

I recently installed `Resharper` code analysing plugin in the `Visual Studio 2022` and started seeing the following error in the Angular application.

[image]

The `createAction` is a method from `NgRx` method. The application compiles well though the IDE shows the error.

I tried a few things (1) changed the Typescript version to 3.0 in resharper (2) replaced the object `{searchTerm: string .... pageSize: number}` with a class. But I still get the same error.

The error is in the following code:

```
export const loadPeople = createAction('[People Fetch] Load People',
    props<{
        searchTerm: string,
        sortOrder: string,
        pageNumber: number,
        pageSize: number
    }>());
```

The type definition for createAction in `action_creator.d.ts`:

```
export declare function createAction<T extends string, P extends object>(type: T, config: ActionCreatorProps<P> & NotAllowedCheck<P>): ActionCreator<T, (props: P & NotAllowedCheck<P>) => P & TypedAction<T>>;
```

`Resharper` does not support typescript 4.0. Should it support Typescript 4.0 to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is visual studio or resharper.
It has a lower version of TypeScript, which doesn't support the TypeScript features that are used for `createAction`.

Comment: Resharper is using typescript version 3.0. The typescript version in the Angular app is 4.8.3.

Comment: Is the problem similar to the issue: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3562